# Remove slicers involvement in a calculation

Tags: powerbi

I have two excel sheets I wan't to see the % diff between.

Unfortunately they are both very different in the setup why I created some calculations.

However, for some reason my Quarter slicer changes my calculation to be smaller than it is.

See picture:

[image]

Can I make my slicer not affect Q1 but only AMOUNT column?

Thanks,

PS: I can't create a Q1 calculation (summing Jan, Feb and March) from AMOUNT due to its format - I need the slicer.)

Comment: Do you have some source data? Can you also tell us what you expect and what your problem is. Your slicer is changing the calc, please de more specific.

Comment: Hi @Aldert thanks for your reponse! I wan't to make the slicer only affect one of the numbers. So I want it to affect "AMOUNT" and not "Q1". Is that possible? I tried edit interactions but that doesn't work with calculations within a table.